# Spring MVC http 500 error apache

Tags: spring, apache, model-view-controller

[image]

Above is the directory hierarchy of my program

I am new to spring and learning MVC concepts I have written a program which takes input(Name) into a text box and prints Hello...'name'. Tha following is my directory structure and the various files I have created.

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" version="3.1">
  <display-name>MVC_HelloWorld</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file> 
  </welcome-file-list>

  <!-- default configuration -->
  <servlet>
   <servlet-name>HelloWorld</servlet-name>
   <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>hello</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.ap</url-pattern> <!-- this same extension should bbe used in form action -->
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

HelloWorld-servlet.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN 2.0//EN"
"http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans-2.0.dtd">

<beans>
<!-- default handler mapping -->
<!--  file should be created under web inf annd it's view resolver file -->

  <!-- handler(Not rqd in case of default handler) -->
  <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping" />

  <!-- controller configuration -->
<bean name="/HelloWorld.ap" class="controller.HelloController"> <!-- mapping url pattern to controller class using 'name' -->

<!-- view resolver -->

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
       <property name="prefix" vlaue="/"/> <!-- default location (prefix used foor rqd page locations) -->
       |<property name="sufix" value=".jsp"/> <!-- sufix used forr rqd page extensions -->

</bean>

</bean>

</beans>
```

HelloController.java

```
package controller;

import java.util.HashMap;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.Controller;

import com.sun.javafx.collections.MappingChange.Map;

public class HelloController implements Controller {

    @Override
    public ModelAndView handleRequest(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws Exception {

        String name=req.getParameter("name");

        Map m= new HashMap();   // creating output object
           m.put("msg","Hello..."+name);

          ModelAndView mav=new ModelAndView("success"+m);



        return mav;
    }

}
```

index.jsp

```
<h1> Hello World</h1>

<form action="./hello.ap">

NAME: <input type="text" name="name">
      <input type="Submit" value="Say Hello">
</form>
```

success.jsp

```
${msg}
```

when I am running this code the index.jsp page is running properly bur upon further execution It shows Error 404.
what's wrong with the code..??
I am using **Eclipse oxygen** in that **apache 8.5**

Comment: Do you have this new ModelAndView("success"+m); with a '+' in your code? ModelAndView(String viewName, Map model). Instead of import com.sun.javafx.collections.MappingChange.Map; use java.util.Map. Spring has  nice annotations like Controller, RequestMapping etc. Please check [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_web_mvc_framework.htm)

Comment: after that getting new error 500- Error instantiating servlet class org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet

Comment: @awagenhoffer the problem remains same after clearing your suggested points it shows 404 error

Answer (score 0):

Your servlet name in definition is `HelloWorld`
but in mapping servlet, is `hello`.
These names must be the same.

Answer (score 0):

```
<servlet>
   <servlet-name>HelloWorld</servlet-name>
   <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>hello</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.ap</url-pattern> <!-- this same extension should bbe used in form action -->
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

here you have used HelloWorld as the servlet name previously and you referring to that as hello later on which is not correct so please correct that just change the hello in servelt-mapping to HelloWorld and access the servlet as HelloWorld.ap it will work.

Comment: I did it but doesn't really make any change...sry