# Can't reach the page eclipse

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, runtime-error

I am getting following errors while running a simple Spring MVC program

```
Aug 11, 2017 3:41:31 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
WARNING: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library failed to load. The error reported was [C:\apache-tomcat-8.5.4\bin\tcnative-1.dll: Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform]
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\apache-tomcat-8.5.4\bin\tcnative-1.dll: Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jni.Library.<init>(Library.java:42)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jni.Library.initialize(Library.java:178)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.init(AprLifecycleListener.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.isAprAvailable(AprLifecycleListener.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.setProtocol(Connector.java:587)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.<init>(Connector.java:70)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ConnectorCreateRule.begin(ConnectorCreateRule.java:64)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.startElement(Digester.java:1188)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1461)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:578)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:629)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:311)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:494)

Aug 11, 2017 3:41:35 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:MVC_HelloWorld' did not find a matching property.
Aug 11, 2017 3:41:35 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.5.4
Aug 11, 2017 3:41:35 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server built:          Jul 6 2016 08:43:30 UTC
Aug 11, 2017 3:41:35 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server number:         8.5.4.0
Aug 11, 2017 3:41:35 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Name:               Windows 10
Aug 11, 2017 3:41:35 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Version:            10.0
Aug 11, 2017 3:41:35 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Architecture:          amd64
Aug 11, 2017 3:41:35 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_144
Aug 11, 2017 3:41:35 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Version:           1.8.0_144-b01
Aug 11, 2017 3:41:35 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
Aug 11, 2017 3:41:35 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_BASE:         C:\Users\Alok\Desktop\Workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
Aug 11, 2017 3:41:35 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_HOME:         C:\apache-tomcat-8.5.4
Aug 11, 2017 3:41:35 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\Users\Alok\Desktop\Workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
Aug 11, 2017 3:41:35 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\apache-tomcat-8.5.4
Aug 11, 2017 3:41:35 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=C:\Users\Alok\Desktop\Workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps
Aug 11, 2017 3:41:35 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\apache-tomcat-8.5.4\endorsed
Aug 11, 2017 3:41:35 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252
Aug 11, 2017 3:41:40 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8081"]
Aug 11, 2017 3:41:45 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Aug 11, 2017 3:41:45 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Aug 11, 2017 3:41:45 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Aug 11, 2017 3:41:45 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 34053 ms
Aug 11, 2017 3:41:46 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Aug 11, 2017 3:41:46 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.4
Aug 11, 2017 3:41:53 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/MVC_HelloWorld]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:911)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:890)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:152)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1403)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1393)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/MVC_HelloWorld]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:158)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Servlet mapping specifies an unknown servlet name HelloWorld
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.addServletMapping(StandardContext.java:3124)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.addServletMapping(StandardContext.java:3103)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureContext(ContextConfig.java:1367)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1181)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:771)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:298)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:94)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5076)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:152)
    ... 6 more

Aug 11, 2017 3:41:53 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:911)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:152)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:152)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:791)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:152)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:655)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:355)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:495)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1403)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1393)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:919)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:890)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:152)
    ... 6 more

Aug 11, 2017 3:41:53 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
SEVERE: The required Server component failed to start so Tomcat is unable to start.
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardServer[8005]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:655)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:355)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:495)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardService[Catalina]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:791)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:152)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:152)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:919)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:152)
    ... 11 more

Aug 11, 2017 3:41:53 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8081"]
Aug 11, 2017 3:41:53 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Aug 11, 2017 3:41:53 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
INFO: Stopping service Catalina
Aug 11, 2017 3:41:53 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8081"]
Aug 11, 2017 3:41:53 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
```

I am using **eclipse oxygen** and **apache tomcatv8.5**  any solutions
I have changed the default port 8080 to 8081 and tried deleting and adding again the server also.. still it's not working and it's unable to start.

I also tried to manually start it using startup.bat but too didn't work is there any jar file missing or something else is the issue?

Comment: It seems you run Tomcat on a Java 64 bit JVM instead of Java 32 bit: _Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform_

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Eclipse 404 error page not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45638046/eclipse-404-error-page-not-found)

Answer (score 0):

problem reported exactly in this line :

> `Servlet mapping specifies an unknown servlet name HelloWorld`

it seems you copied some codes from sample projects or tutorials and forget to change some names or definitions.
try to find this

> HelloWorld

servlet name in your

> web.xml

file and change it to your own servlet name.

Comment: I have written the same name as written in action tag. Could you plz exactly point to the error I made

Comment: Check your web.xm for servlet definitions.

Comment: then what should I write in action tag this is the complete program https://stackoverflow.com/q/45505216/6487700..I don't know whether program directory is wrong or the syntax is wrong..plz help me

Comment: See my answer over there