# Eclipse 404 error page not found

Tags: spring-mvc

I am trying spring MVC program and this is my directory structure when I run this program it works properly and when I hit the enter key and direct it to the next page i.e the action page.

[image]

it shows this page

```
HTTP Status 404 - /MVC_HelloWorld/hello.ap


type Status report

message /MVC_HelloWorld/hello.ap

description The requested resource is not available.
```

In my form action page I have written
this my inde.jsp page

```
<h1> Hello World</h1>

<form action="./hello.ap">

NAME: <input type="text" name="name">
      <input type="Submit" value="Say Hello">
</form>
```

Is the problem with the path or directory structure is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The directory structure as I can see is correct. But the action you are setting in the form should be only the text like "hello.ap" it should not include / or ./ try with hello.ap and name the requestMaping in your controller to hello.ap.

Comment: That I did but it makes no change

Comment: this is the complete program https://stackoverflow.com/q/45505216/6487700.. this is the code before I made the modifications, so kindly tell me suggestions on this..What's wrong in it ?

Comment: I have answered your question there please take a look into that.